# Array is empty in debugger watch

Tags: c, avr

When I look in the debugger watch, with breakpoint at `_render`, `command` containins only `0x00`.
This is for a AVR processor.

```
int main(){
    char hello[] = "Hello";
    gfx_put_string(5, hello);
}

void gfx_put_string(int length, char* characters){
    char command[length+3];
    command[0] = 0x00; //cmd
    command[1] = 0x06; //cmd
    for (int i=0; i<length; i++){
        command[i+2] = characters[i];
    }
    command[length+2] = 0x00; //end with null
    _render(length+3, command);
}
```

Want it to contain `0x00, 0x06, H, e, l, l, o, 0x00`. What is wrong with my code? How can I fix it?

Edit: Suggested fix was to change the first character in the array not being 0x00 (null), but no change. Optmization is turned of. XC8 None (-O0)

Found it in memory though(?)
[image: Image of memory]

Comment: Arrays must initialize with a constant value

Comment: I'm only putting this as a comment since I'm not 100% sure. But my guess would be that while Variable length arrays are part of the c standard, they are optional to implement. It's very possible your debugger just pretends they're `char*`. In which case it would be right to think that a c str terminates at 0x0. You could confirm that by writing something other than 0 to the first byte, or checking the other elements of command individually.

Comment: `in the debugger watch, with breakpoint at _render, command containins only 0x00` What debugger are you using and how do you check that command contains only 0x00?

Comment: It has been known for debuggers to interpret all arrays as NUL-terminated.  This error can result in debug inspection to display 'nothing' when an array with valid data starts with a zero:(

Comment: @LucaRicardo automatic arrays do not have to. `calloc` is the worst choice on 8 bits tiny microcontrollers. Never ever use it.  You comments are wrong and should be deleted

Comment: @Anic17 wrong comment.

Comment: Everything is wrong for you I see. You can't initialize arrays with a variable length. `int var = rand(); char arr[var+1]; // wrong`

Comment: @KamilCuk im using the built in, in atmel studio / microchip studio

Comment: @Anic simply your comment is wrong. You do not know VLAs

Comment: @George never use `malloc` family functions when programing tiny AVR chips.

Comment: What does the debugger show if you ask it to display the single elements of the array? -- What does it show if you change the type from `char command[...` to `uint8_t command[...`?

Comment: @Anic17 really? https://godbolt.org/z/n6hdhqf96

Comment: @Anic17 *`You can't initialize arrays with a variable length`* 1. It is not initialization only **definition** 2. Did you ever hear about VLAs? Probably your experience is only limited to VS and Microsoft compiler does fully implement features form C99.

Comment: Can you try like with a constant volatile buiffer `void _render(..) { volatile char buffer[20]; for (int i = 0; i < 7; ++i) buffer[i] = command[i]; __asm__("bkpt");` and see then in the debugger if there are data in the debugger in such buffer? Do you have any input/output means that you can print the `command` out and check it in something else then the debugger?

Comment: Possibly your debugger is interpreting the `char` array as a string and displaying its contents up to the first null character. There is probably a way to ask your debugger to show the full contents of the array. However, you have not stated what debugger you are using. Check its documentation for commands or settings to show more elements of the array.

Comment: yeah think so too about the \0 in first. try  command[0] = 'A'; and command[1] as well and see what that does in the debugger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was something with the `command` array being variable length, when I set the length to a const everything worked out as expected. Final code below:

```
void gfx_put_string(const int length, char* characters){
    char command[length+3];
    command[0] = 0x00;
    command[1] = 0x06; //cmd
    
    for (int i=0; i<length; i++){
        command[i+2] = characters[i];
    }
    command[length+2] = 0x00; //end with null

   _render(length+3, command);
}
```

Comment: So this is a flaw of the debugger and/or IDE that did not grasp the size of the array. Oops.